# Java (JUnit5) Testing challenge

Tags: java, time

I have a class of convenience methods relating to DateTime which gets things like the current year or current hour. I've just updated it all to use the java.time.* classes and am trying to write good JUnit 5 tests to make sure they work correctly.

I obviously need to determine an expected result to compare to each actual result but I'm having trouble thinking of a good way to *compute* the expected result. (Hard-coding the expected value is not very satisfactory for values like the current hour, minute or second and even bigger units like day are problematic if I don't do the testing on the day specified in the expected results.)

My methods are based on the LocalDate.now() method so it seems pointless to compute the expected results using the same method; that might only prove that the expected and actual results are the same but BOTH wrong. Is this a reasonable objection?

If it is, then what way should I calculate the expected results? Many of the old date and time classes are largely deprecated and everyone knows about their deficiencies. Should I use them anyway and hope none of those deficiencies gives me false positives or negatives?

Or is there a better way to proceed?

Comment: It seems to me that you’re trying to write a test for the LocalDate class... If your method returns LocalDate.now() that’s exactly what you should test it against

Comment: I think what you want is [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) and [`LocalDate.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now(java.time.Clock)). This is explicitly there for testability.

Comment: @Tomaz Fernandes - so you want me to test LocalDate.now() against itself? How could that ever fail to give the exact same answers, which *might* be the wrong answers?

Comment: @Ole V.V. - You're suggesting that I test the clock used by LocaleDate.now() against a different clock? That makes a lot more sense to me :-) Thank you!

Comment: What I’m saying is you don’t have to test the java classes... If your method returns the current year, your test should test it against LocalDate.now().getYear(), and then go on with your life... Otherwise you’re far more likely to produce an bug in your testing suite than in your utility class, which kind of defeats the purpose of having tests. Anyway, that’s just my two cents :)

Comment: But seeing the answer from Henry it looks like there is a option where you can force the LocalDate clock to be set at an specific value, so that’s surely better... Going to research on that.